# SQL Server Replication issues

Tags: sql-server, replication

Before I begin - I'm *not* a DBA type, I'm a software dev type. Our DBA has been out sick for the last week or so, and I've been trying to get a new feature of ours up and running.

This new feature involved adding a couple tables and views to an existing replication subscription, so I added the articles to the subscription using the UI in SSMS. Nothing happened, so I tried running the snapshot agent.

Looking at the monitor for the snapshot agent, it appears that everything actually finishes within the first 3-4 seconds of it running. In the log I see things like:

`[0%] Activated articles for publication '[publicationname]' at the publisher.`

`[0%] Bulk copying snapshot data for article 'new_table_name'`

`[0%] Bulk copied snapshot data for article 'new_table_name' (1068 rows).`

(previous two rows repeat for each new table)

Then the progress skips from 0% to 93%:

`[93%] Pre-loading meta-data of all tables in the publisher database for scripting`

`[93%] Pre-loading meta-data of all stored procedures in the publisher database for scripting`

`[93%] Pre-loading meta-data of all views in the publisher database for scripting`

`[93%] Pre-loading meta-data of all user-defined functions in the publisher database for scripting`

`[93%] Sorting article objects in the proper creation order`

Then, I start seeing lots of these:

`[93%] The published object [objectnamehere] (StoredProcedure) is dependent on the unpublished object [objectnamehere] (Table), creation of the published object at the subscriber may fail unless the dependency is satisfied ahead of time.`

But they're all for things I don't particularly care about... but I'm not positive I can remove them from the publication without breaking anything. There are ~20-30 of these.

Then, the agent runs for a bit without doing anything. After 10 min I get this:

`[93%] The process is running and is waiting for a response from the server.`

And then two more every 10 mins until it times out:

`Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.`

Now, it looks like the regular transaction replication isn't working either because there's no good current snapshot.

Needless to say, I'm in it pretty deep and I REALLY need some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out I had a couple other jobs running that were blocking the snapshot agent. As explained here: http://www.sqlmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/sql-server-replication/8439/Timeout-error-running-snapshot-agent

The snapshot agent requires an exclusive lock, so it was timing out waiting for the lock. Disabling the jobs and then re-running the agent worked (and it only took ~5 sec).

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing the -QueryTimeOut of the agent.

Comment: it would need to take more than 30 min?

Comment: Depends on your data size.